# posting json data from c# windows application to php page

Tags: c#, php, json

How do I post  a json string from c# windows application to a php page?

I am using the following code but it returns null string from php page?

```
string Uname, pwd, postData, postData1;
            Uname = txtUname.EditValue.ToString();
            pwd = txtPassword.EditValue.ToString();

            List<request1> JSlist = new List<request1>();
            request1 obj = new request1();
            obj.emailid = Uname;
            obj.password = pwd;
            JSlist.Add(obj);

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string s;
            s = serializer.Serialize(obj);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://lab.amusedcloud.com/test/login_action.php");

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            MessageBox.Show(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer);

            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

PHP

```
<?php
$json_array = json_decode($_POST['json']);

?>
```

connection established successfully but this php page returns `array(0){}`

Comment: What are you expecting the PHP page to return?  Currently that code doesn't output anything.

Comment: Have you tried to examine the traffic using developer tools of chrome or fiddler and see where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ContentType property, it looks like you should be form encoding the content your sending to the PHP script.  If thats the case you need to make sure the content you are sending is in key/value format:

```
[key]=[value]
```

In your case it looks like the PHP script is expecting a parameter with the key "json", so the data your sending would be something like:

```
"json=" & s
```

Hope that helps.